# using parameters for unknown column name s?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

Is it possible to write a query similar to the one in my code below where the column that is set can vary depending on user selection from the front end? In this case `@Column` and `@Value` are selected from an interface

```
  SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
["connectToEnterpriseAssignmentDB"].ToString());
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();

                string currency = lstCurrency.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
                string columnCurr = lstColumnCurr.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
                double value = double.Parse(txtValue.Text);
                currency= currency.Trim();
                columnCurr=columnCurr.Trim();         

                cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE CurrencyTbl SET @Column = '@Value' WHERE CurrencyName = '@Currency'";

                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Currency", SqlDbType.Char).Value = currency;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Column", SqlDbType.Char).Value = columnCurr;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Float).Value = value;

                cmd1.Connection = connect;
                connect.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connect.Close();
```

Comment: You can't use a parameter to represent a column name.

Comment: By the way '@Value'  and '@Currency' are not parameter placeholders. Text within single quotes is a Literal text (in other words your code search a record where CurrencyName contains the word '@Currency'. You should remove the quotes

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use column name as variable, instead you can use that from C# directly as below:

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
["connectToEnterpriseAssignmentDB"].ToString());
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();

                string currency = lstCurrency.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
                string columnCurr = lstColumnCurr.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
                double value = double.Parse(txtValue.Text);
                currency= currency.Trim();
                columnCurr=columnCurr.Trim();         

                cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE CurrencyTbl SET "+columnCurr + " = '@Value' WHERE CurrencyName = '@Currency'";

                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Currency", SqlDbType.Char).Value = currency;
                //cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Column", SqlDbType.Char).Value = columnCurr;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Float).Value = value;

                cmd1.Connection = connect;
                connect.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connect.Close();
```

Comment: Im getting the error `Error converting data type varchar to float.`  any ideas?