# Error converting data type varchar to float.?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

Im getting this error and dont know what the issue is.
The database column I'm updating has the datatype float and at the `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();` part of the code the error is popping up.
Any ideas?

```
 SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ["connectToEnterpriseAssignmentDB"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();

            string currency = lstCurrency.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
            string columnCurr = lstColumnCurr.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
            float value = float.Parse(txtValue.Text);
            currency = currency.Trim();
            columnCurr = columnCurr.Trim();

            cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE CurrencyTbl SET " + columnCurr + " = '@Value' WHERE CurrencyName = '@Currency'";

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Currency", SqlDbType.Char).Value = currency;
            //cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Column", SqlDbType.Char).Value = columnCurr;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Float).Value = value;

            cmd1.Connection = connect;
            connect.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connect.Close();
```

Comment: Plz post here more details on the exception you get

Comment: A already explained here (and elsewhere), don't enclose numeric values in quotes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904032/using-parameters-for-unknown-column-name-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes.  You are passing in the parameters with the correct type:

```
       cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE CurrencyTbl SET " + columnCurr + " = @Value WHERE CurrencyName = @Currency";
```

Comment: And do put quotes around @Currency